# Ordering hashtags in file by frequency and sending that to another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the goal is to use a file full of tweets, to find the most occurring hashtags(#) and rank them by frequency in another file
so far i have this

```
import collections
with open("/Users/Adnan/Desktop/twitter_data.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        for part in line.split():
            if "#" in part:
                print(part)
                print(collections.Counter(part).most_common())
```

and it prints out all the different hashtags in the file. how would i send that to another file ranked by the popularity of the hashtag based on the frequency of it appearing?

something else ive been trying to get to work

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import collections
with open("/Users/Adnan/Desktop/twitter_data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        for part in line.split():
            if "#" in part:
                hashtag = (re.findall(r'(?i)\#\w+', line))
                print(collections.Counter(hashtag).most_common())
```

i got close to it working, but it continues to bug out, really desperate for some help so if anyone can thank you.

sample data: @stellargirl I loooooooovvvvvveee my Kindle2. Not that the DX is cool, but the 2 is fantastic in its own right.
Reading my kindle2...  Love it... Lee childs is good read.
Ok, first assesment of the #kindle2...it rocks

Comment: i found this import re
import collections
from collections import Counter
s = "this #is a #string with several #hashtags #hashtags"
tag = (re.findall(r'(?i)\#\w+', s)) # will includes #
print(collections.Counter(tag).most_common()) but cant figure out how to use this with the file always recieve an error

Comment: Give us a sample of your data so we can help you figure out what's going wrong. Otherwise we have no idea what's going to work for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `collections` module and use `collections.Counter(list_of_hastags).most_common(# most common you want)` to return the most common occurences in your file.

Or if you don't want to limit you don't even need to pass the number of most common occurences.

Small example:

```
import collections
#In your file this will likely be data.readlines() depending on how your file is struct.
#to get the list of hastags, you may need to split etc depending on structure
hashtags = ['#1', '#1', '#2', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#4']
print(collections.Counter(hashtags).most_common())
```

Result:

```
[('#4', 2), ('#1', 2), ('#2', 2), ('#3', 1)]
```

Comment: well it needs to go from highest to lowest of all the different hashtags in the file

Comment: check out [the documentation on `most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), you can omit the number of most common to just get all of them.

Comment: note that the source code actually just does `if n is None: return sorted(self.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

Comment: i added the counter and most common but for some reason keep only receiving one hashtag and not the full list

Comment: thats not working for me, idk maybe i could be doing it wrong ill update it now and show what ive tried

Comment: sample from the .txt file @stellargirl I loooooooovvvvvveee my Kindle2. Not that the DX is cool, but the 2 is fantastic in its own right.
Reading my kindle2...  Love it... Lee childs is good read.
Ok, first assesment of the #kindle2... it rocks. so it needs to recognize the #kindle2 and count how many other times it appears in the file of tweets and rank it among the other hashtags

Comment: i think it may be a mistake in me storing the hashtag words or something, i dont know i cant figure it out for the life of me

Answer (score 0):

you definitely are asking for behaviour defined in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can even insert the nested for loop as a generator expression for the argument:

```
data="""
#1 hello #2
this is #2 a #3 test
#2 life is good #1""".split("\n")

import collections

hashtags = collections.Counter(part
                                for line in data
                                    for part in line.split()
                                        if "#" in part)

print(hashtags.most_common())
```

gives me this output:

```
[('#2', 3), ('#1', 2), ('#3', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the frequencies of each hashtag by making use of the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) datatype as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

freq = Counter()
with open("twitter_data.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        for part in line.split():
            if "#" in part:
                freq[part] += 1
print(freq.most_common())
```

Based on the question and the structure of the existing code, it appears that `twitter_data.txt` looks something like this (each tweet separated by newline):

```
A tweeted about #tag1
B tweeted about #tag2
C tweeted about #tag3
A tweeted about #tag1
A tweeted about #tag1
B tweeted about #tag2
```

Running the code above on this sample file produces the following output:

```
[('#tag1', 3), ('#tag2', 2), ('#tag3', 1)]
```

Comment: when i tried this it only gave 1 hash tag (#'bullying'...)

Comment: @Rashid based on your updated question, you are defining a new `Counter()` within each loop, and not saving the previous one anywhere. You should define `freq = collections.Counter()` at the top-level of your program, and then update that with each occurrence of a hashtag.

Comment: im sorry i dont follow

Comment: i tried what you posted above and came to a point where the program kept running nonstop adding each tag non stop, am i getting close? i feel like im just missing some tiny detail or something